# :public is no longer used to avoid overloading Module#public, use :public_folder instead

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

i am beginner in rails.i have given a project(https://github.com/cloudspokes/cs-website-cms).when i run it with 
command:rails server 
.there is a warning

:public is no longer used to avoid overloading Module#public, use :public_folder instead
    from /home/ritesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@refinery/bundler/gems/resque-c528f41f384b/lib/resque/server.rb:16:in `<class:Server>'
=> Booting Thin
=> Rails 3.2.8 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/home/ritesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@refinery/gems/restforce-0.1.8/lib/restforce/client.rb:281:in`authenticate!': No authentication middleware present (RuntimeError)
    from /home/ritesh/rails_projects/cs-website-cms-master/config/initializers/streaming.rb:11:in `'

and an error No authentication middleware present.
can any one please help me how to get rid of this warning and error??

Answer (score 0):

You should probably be running `foreman start -p 3000` instead of `rails s` command. As it is clearly mentioned in their README file.

Thanks,
Dinesh